# How to center a node within a pane javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, center, pane

How do I create a Pane and have a child `Node` put at the center?

Lets say the `Pane` is `500` by `500` and the `Node` is an `ImageView` with a `200` by `200` `Image`

```
ImageView view = new ImageView();

Image img = new Image("test.png");
view.setImage(img);
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.setMinWidth(500);
pane.setMinHeight(500);
pane.getChildren().add(view);
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a `StackPane`, `HBox`, or `VBox`? They can have their alignment set which will center their children in both dimensions automatically if you use `Pos.CENTER`.

Comment: THe whole idea is that I have an anchor pane and then I want the user to be able to add any layout (VBox, HBox, or Stackpane).  However, the size of the anchor pane changes and has no preferred size.  How would you then center it with whatever layout you use.

Comment: The layout choices you mentioned all solve the issue as I explained above. I am confused. Why do you have to use an `AnchorPane`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you have 2 choices :

1. For example using `StackPane` instead of `Pane` (because you can use [Pos](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html))

   ```
   StackPane p = new StackPane();
   p.setPrefSize(700,700); //set a default size for your stackpane
   Image img = new Image("test.png"); //create an image
   ImageView v = new ImageView(img); //create an imageView and pass the image 

   p.getChildren().add(v); //add imageView to stackPane
   StackPane.setAlignment(v,Pos.CENTER_LEFT); //set it to the Center Left(by default it's on the center)
   stage.setScene(new Scene(p));
   stage.show();
   ```
2. You can use **JavaFx Scene Builder**, it's a visual layout tool for JavaFx.
   For example if I want to create a `Hbox` layout:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

       <?import java.lang.*?>
       <?import java.net.*?>
       <?import java.util.*?>
       <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
       <?import javafx.scene.*?>
       <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
       <?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
       <?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
       <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
       <?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
       <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

       <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="369.0" prefWidth="425.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" >
           <children>
               <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" x="0.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                   <image>
                       <Image url="@../yourImg.png" />
                   </image>
               </ImageView>
           </children>
       </HBox>
   ```

   save-it as `myLayout.fxml` inside your main class and add following to your code:

   ```
   Hbox root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("myLayout.fxml"));
   Scene scene = new Scene(root);
   stage.setScene(scene);
   stage.show();
   ```

Comment: Thanks.  What happens if it's an anchorPane without a preferred size. I tried to just add the stackPane to the Anchor Pane.  However, without the perferred size set the centering won't work.  In my example, the anchor pane can be resized because the left, right, top, and bottom are tabs that can open and can change the size of the center anchor pane.

Answer (score 15):

I usually use the following approach to center a node/pane:

```
<VBox alignment="CENTER">
    <HBox alignment="CENTER">
        <!-- your node/pane -->
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```